# Ng-repeat animation not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, angularjs-ng-repeat, internet-explorer-11

I have this ng-repeat code, but not working in IE 11

```
<div class="cardSegmentation moveUp" 
style="animation: moveUpA {{ (0.5 + 0.1 * $index) + 's' }} ease forwards;animation-delay: 400ms;-webkit-animation: moveUpA {{ (0.5 + 0.1 * $index) + 's' }} ease forwards;-webkit-animation-delay: 400ms;" 
ng-repeat="typesCard in quizzesTypes" 
ng-click="sendTypeSegm(typesCard.id)">
```

In the element inspector, no content is shown in this element:

```
{{ (0.5 + 0.1 * $index) + 's' }}
```

any help please ..

Thank

Comment: Have you tried using ng-style? Typically any bindings must be resolved within an angular attribute, since the base attributes are read as-is and are not preprocessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doesn't recognize it as valid HTML & do nothing with it.

You can either use `ng-attrs-style`  or `ng-style` directive like I shown below.

```
<div class="cardSegmentation moveUp" 
  ng-style="{
     animation: 'moveUpA '+(0.5 + 0.1 * $index) + 's ease forwards',
     animation: 'moveUpA '+ (0.5 + 0.1 * $index) + 's ease forwards',
     -webkit-animation: 'moveUpA '+ (0.5 + 0.1 * $index) + 's ease forwards'
  }"
  style=" animation-delay: 400ms; ; -webkit-animation-delay: 400ms;" 
  ng-repeat="typesCard in quizzesTypes" 
  ng-click="sendTypeSegm(typesCard.id)">
```